# Сборка проекта в Unity под Android, получаю ошибку: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/core-utils_release.kotlin_module'

Tags: android, unity3d

Unity 2019.4.31f1.

Ошибка:

> Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/core-utils_release.kotlin_module'.

в файле mainTemplate.gradle перепробовал различные варианты исключения:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/main.kotlin_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
        exclude ('kotlin/*' + '*')
        exclude "**/kotlin/**"        
}
```

Ничего это не помогает.

Настройки в Unity Project Settings->Player:
[image: Настройки в Unity Project Settings->Player:]

Есть идеи, как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482906/android-gradle-build-duplicate-entry-meta-inf-app-release-kotlin-module) смотрели?

Comment: JackFromBB, да, конечно :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я исправил эту ошибку, использовав Custom Launcher Gradle Template, чекнув соответствующую галочку в настройках Unity Project Settings->Player (выше есть скрин без этой галочки). И добавив соответствующий блок исключений в сформированный файл launcherTemplate.gradle с исключением вида

```
exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
```

и это помогло.